# export declare type ResourceType = Lowercase<Protocol.Network.ResourceType>, Error building Angular app with Puppeteer and typscript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for text extraction in the Angular app. I installed puppeteer using npm.
I am using node version 14.7.3
and typescript version 3.9.6
and puppeteer version 11.0.0

I used below code in component.ts file -
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

I am getting this error in terminal:
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Lowercase'. 6437 export declare type ResourceType = Lowercase<Protocol.Network.ResourceType>

What is the cause of this error?
How can I resolve this error?
How to include puppeteer library with Angular?

Comment: For Text extraction from url using puppeteer, i used this reference : https://scrapingant.com/blog/puppeteer-get-all-text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: even when I have not added any code related to puppeteer lib, still giving this error

Comment: it's maybe some error in installation, or compatibility issue, i don't know what is causing this issue?